# QGIS Georeferencer--result raster far away and distorted

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I've been trying to georeference a raster.The ground control points I choose using 'from map canvas' are quite close to the original points, but the results are far far away and distorted. Could anyone help with it? The screenshots are below:
1. After choosing GCPs and setting up transformation parameters, you can see the red lines indicating the to-be-moved-to positions:
[image]

2. the GCPs in QGIS:

[image: ![enter image description here]

3. The result raster is distorted and far far away from original location:
   [image]

Comment: What are you transformation parameters? I get the best result using the Helmert transformation.

Comment: I used linear, but I don't think it's the problem. No matter linear or hermert, it should be shifted so far away.

Comment: I wonder if the georeferencer is dropping decimals. Now all the GCPs seem to be very close to each other, many even at exactly same coordinates. I would try to give the ground control points in some metric coordinates instead of degrees.

Comment: Use a different CRS.

Comment: Will try a different CRS

Comment: didn't work either using another CRS.